# System does not boot anymore after updating to kernel 5.13.0-27

Tags: boot, kernel, scripts

I am using 20.04.

Boot always stops dead at "Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount" - and not only for 30 seconds, but completely.

When I go back one kernel version, everything works fine.

What can I do?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have the same problem but how do you know where it stops: I only have a blank screen. Recovery mode works, though,and older kernels also.